# What is the dependancy for EmbeddedActiveMQBroker?

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven and not sure how to write dependancies for my pom.xml

I am trying to use the following class:

```
import org.apache.activemq.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQBroker;
```

And this is my attempt at writing a dependancy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId> 
    <artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId> 
    <version>5.15.9</version>
</dependency>
```

But I am still getting an error

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId>
    <version>5.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can get the details from mvnrepository.com.

Comment: I checked on mvnreposity.com and it lists the dependancy as (sorry for the format):

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    <version>5.13.1</version>
</dependency>

But this one still gives me an error. Why would they list it if it throws an error?

Comment: how did you know that you needed to add the "tooling" part to the dependency

Comment: Is it working for you, I was checking in mvnrepository.com.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we go to the official Maven Dependencies Page of ActiveMQ - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-broker/5.15.9.

Then, we go to the "Test Dependencies" category, where we clearly can see the `JUnit` artifact.

so, use in your `pom.xml` file next dependency for version 5.15.19:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-broker -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**

Add also the next dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq.tooling/activemq-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @klippy, you can try this what BSeitkazin has mentioned. I will delete my post.

Comment: Using this version of the dependancy gives me the following error: The import org.apache.activemq.junit cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I used this four dependencies in a project that uses `EmbeddedActiveMQBroker` for integration tests:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${activemq-junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${activemq-junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${activemq-junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${activemq-junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```